# String concatenate TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am following a tutorial and I am getting an error.

My code should be this:

```
salaries = {'John':'20','Sally':'30','Sammy':'15'}
print(salaries['John'])

salaries['John'] = salaries['John'] + 30
print(salaries['John'])
```

I am getting back an error like this

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "print.py", line 9, in
>   
>       salaries['John'] = salaries['John'] + 30 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Sorry for not knowing how to post a code . It's my first time here.

Comment: salaries is a dictionary and you try to only add 1 value, try adding a key-value pair.

Comment: you cannot multiply or add anything with/to print function output

Comment: Could you maybe add your desired outcome because right now it is not really clear what you want to do?

Comment: Thank you , it's a python 3.7 thing cause the guy in the tutorial is making this exactly like I wrote.

Comment: All I wanted to do is add to John's pay :))

Comment: @Alex So you want to add 30 to the salaries of John making it 50?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
salaries['John'] = str(int(salaries['John']) + 30)
```

You need to convert the salaries of John to an int add 30 and then convert it back to a string.

This will change `salaries['John']` from 20 to 50

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to include the 30 you'd have to put something like `str(30)`. That's why it's giving you that error cause 30 is an int and the rest are strings you can't combine strings and ints. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Alex , seems we're from the same country :) I tried that but at the end I get the first salary of John and then when changing 30 to str(30) I am getting the previous salaty put together like 2030.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood. If you want to add them then leave the 30 as an int and then try this int(salaries['John']) to print that you would str() the whole thing. Where are you from?

Comment: Thank you Alex, Tobias made a little bit more clear for noobs like me ;))) it's my first time among this python and I feel like an idiot .

Comment: No worries.  We all have to start somewhere. Just be sure to accept the answer you like as it can help other beginners learn too.

Answer (score 0):

The "+" operator is using for concatenate strings, adding numbers, etc.
in your case you trying to add two integers but in your dictionary "salaries" the values are strings.
you can convert the value to int, adding the numbers and then convert to string to store the value.

Try this:

```
salaries['John'] = str(int(salaries['John']) + 30)
print(salaries['John'])
```