# Machine Learning: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I'm new to this machine learning, as the title says I have this error in the code and I can't solve it, I'm working on Python 3.7 in Pycharm.

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str -

```py
# where "Último" is a df with prices.

pred = []
for i in range(0,valid.shape[0]):
    a = train["Último"][len(train)-925+i:].sum() + sum(pred)
    b = a/925
    pred.append(b)
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. From what I can say, either of the operands to operator `'+'` is a string, so it's expecting other operand a string.

Comment: Such question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465931/string-concatenate-typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str